# iOS: ActionSheetStringPicker successAction: wrong selection

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, uiactionsheet

I am using the ActionSheetStringPicker from the ActionSheetPickers3.0 (since I no longer can use the old picker views because of iOS 8).  This is how I am calling the method:

```
ActionSheetStringPicker *genderPicker = [[ActionSheetStringPicker alloc] 
initWithTitle:@"Gender" rows:categoryTypes initialSelection:nil target:self 
successAction:@selector(selectedGender:) cancelAction:@selector(cancelledGender) 
origin:gender];

[genderPicker showActionSheetPicker];
```

My success action code is this:

```
-(void) selectedGender:(NSNumber *)genderSelected {

    NSLog(@"selected gender: %@",genderSelected);

    if (genderSelected == 0) {
        NSLog(@"male");
        gender.text = @"Male";
    } else {
        NSLog(@"female");
        gender.text = @"Female";
    }
}
```

I am getting either a 1 or 0 value from the selected gender (male/female) when I NSLog the genderSelected value.  My problem is that in my if-statement it always says I picked female.  I'm getting the correct value that I select from the picker, but can't seem to figure out what the problem is.  Does anyone know how I can get my if-statement working?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your success callback method the parameter you are getting is of type NSNumber. You cannot directly compare the object of type NSNumber with int value 0. Therefore use the following :

```
if (genderSelected.intValue == 0) {
    NSLog(@"male");
    gender.text = @"Male";
} else {
    NSLog(@"female");
    gender.text = @"Female";
}
```

Comment: I actually tried casting genderSelected as an int value and it still did not work, but you get an upvote for the effort.  Like this: (int)genderSelected == 0

Comment: Try as I have written in code above. It will work :]

Comment: Ridiculous! Why would that work and not casting.. Well, I've changed my code to match yours because that is more efficient than converting to a string for comparison.  Thanks!

Comment: You were trying to downcast an "Object" of Type NSNumber to a primitive data type. Thats why it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Well this isn't exactly what I was looking for, but it worked.  I set the NSNumber that I was getting as an NSString then compared to a "0" and "1" string. Here is my solution:

```
-(void) selectedGender:(NSNumber *)genderSelected {

NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",genderSelected];

    if ([string isEqualToString:@"0"]) {
        NSLog(@"male");
    } else if ([string isEqualToString:@"1"]) {
        NSLog(@"female");
    }
}
```